# Don't request parent route's model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've got a blog. Single blog-posts appear under `/blog/post-title`, a list of post under `/blog/`

Whenever I access a single blog-post like `http://example.com/blog/post-title` it also requests a list of posts from the parent-route:

[image]

For a single blog post the list of posts is not required. **How can I prevent loading the parent's model (the list of posts)?**

This is the `router.js`:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('base', { 'path' : '/' }, function() {
    this.route('blog', { 'path' : 'blog/'}, function() {
      this.route('post', { 'path' : ':permalink' })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Are the posts embedded?

Comment: What do you mean by embedded? YOu can see the page live at http://ali.dj

Comment: Are the posts embedded records on blog as in does the response for blog contain the post ids or the actual posts.

Comment: It contains the actual posts.

Comment: That means they are embedded, what you want to do is side load them, what are you using for the backend?

Comment: The backend is Sails (a MVC-framework for Express). All posts are requested like this: http://ali.dj/api/v1/posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Add a nested route 'index' under blog:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('base', { 'path' : '/' }, function() {
    this.route('blog', { 'path' : 'blog/'}, function() {
      this.route('index', { 'path': '/' });
      this.route('post', { 'path' : ':permalink' })
    })
  })
})
```

2) Move your logic from 'blog' controller to 'blog.index', also move template logic from blog to blog.index.